# Filter dates between two day-month combination for each different year in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a large spatial dataset (150 milion) with points over time for 10 different years. I'd like to get objects between, for example, 15 january and 15 june for each year in a simple and efficient query.

Is there any day-month datetime format in postgresql? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: A bit of research would go a long way: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html. You probably want to use the [`BETWEEN` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) which can also operate on dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
where (extract(month from the_date_column), extract(day from the_date_column)) 
       between (1,15) and (6,15)
```

That can make use of an index:

```
create index on the_table ( extract(month from the_date_column), extract(day from the_date_column) ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first solution would not fit as would only get 1-15 days for all months and not the interval between both dates including all dates in between.

Is the index queryable as kind of date-time afterwards?

Comment: The condition returns all rows where the date lies between 15 january and 15 june ignoring the year, so e.g. January 20th, or May 19

Answer (score 0):

An alternative

```
where to_char(the_date_column, 'mmdd') between '0115' and '0615'
```

and a corresponding index

```
create index on the_table (to_char(the_date_column, 'mmdd')) ;
```